# Use entire drive when writing disk with DD

Tags: dd, disk-image

How do I go about making DD use the entire space of a drive when I write an image to it? When I write a 1gb image to an 8gb USB, I get a 1gb partition, and the rest of the storage space is unused. I want to write the 1gb IMG to the drive and have the entire drive all be one partition. I'm trying to figure out how to do this with only one command, so I'm not resizing the partition to fill the drive after.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task of dd is to write the image as it is, so dd does not expand the partition. What you can do is after the operation to expand the partition, try GParted. To do it by a command line, I need to know what kind of file system you create (Reiser, ext3, ext4, fat32?)

Comment: ext4. I’m using it to build an installer for my ultra light linux distro. So there isn’t any gparted/parted I can use since it’s minimal packages for a running system + x server.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/8/resize2fs - That should do it.

Comment: That’s awesome! Can it expand to the entire drive?

Comment: You need to unmount it and then you can do it: umount /dev/sdX && resize2fs -p /dev/sdX

Comment: Thank you!! This saved my entire project lol